# Cannot assign a value of type 'MyClass' to a value of type 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate!'

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to send email the following way in iOS:

```
var picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
picker.setSubject("Mic Data")

var messageBody = NSMutableString()

for var index = 0; index<array.count; index++ {
    messageBody.appendString(String(format: "%@\n", arguments: [array.objectAtIndex(index) as! String]))
}

picker.setMessageBody(messageBody as String, isHTML: false)

presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I get error on line `picker.mailComposeDelegate = self`. But it should work. I've set delegate this way `class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` and used delegate method:

```
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` to your class instead of `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`. Easy mistake to make.